# How do I get rid of this H1 tag?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the HTML structure on my Wordpress site to make more sense, and am trying to figure out how the designer set it up many years ago. It appears that the site logo must be an H1 tag for the logo to appear. I don't want the site logo to be an H1, but if I just remove the H1 tags, the logo no longer appears. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <header>
<div class="logo"><h1><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1></div>
            </div>
    </header>
```

And then in the style sheet, it has:

```
/*  HEADER */
header h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
header h1 a { display: block; background: url(images/logo.png); background-size:302px 21px; width: 302px; height: 21px; text-indent: -9999px; }
header h1 + p { margin: 0; display: none; }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything apart from just deleting the h1 tag?

Comment: What do you want it to be?

Comment: try to replace `h1` in css with `.logo` | but why do you want to change that ?

Comment: I tried deleting the H1 tag out of the HTML and out of the style sheet and that didn't work. When I delete the H1 out of the HTML and replace the `H1`s in the `/*  HEADER */` section of the style sheet with `.logo`, it doesn't work either.

Vaku and Robby- I don't want the logo to be an H1 because that's not great structure. I want the title of the page to be the only H1 on the page. I want the logo to just be the logo without any header tags.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the CSS you posted, the background image is being shown largely because of the following:

```
background: url(images/logo.png)
```

To fix your problem, add some CSS that looks like this:

```
.logo {
    background: url(images/logo.png);
    background-size:302px 21px;
    width: 302px;
    height: 21px;
}
```

And replace your header with markup that looks roughly like this:

```
<header>
    <div class="logo"><!-- your logo should appear here --></div>
    <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1> 
</header>
```

You can read more about how background images work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. My intention, though, is to remove the `h1` from the markup. If I do that with what you've suggested, the image still doesn't show up for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove the h1? this is standard practice, to have your logo in your header as an h1.

Anyways, if you still want to do it, you can remove your h1 tag from your logo, and in your css change:

```
header h1 a { display: block; background: url(images/logo.png); background-size:302px 21px; width: 302px; height: 21px; text-indent: -9999px; }
```

to

```
header your_new_element a { display: block; background: url(images/logo.png); background-size:302px 21px; width: 302px; height: 21px; text-indent: -9999px; }
```

where "your_new_element" is whatever tag you replaced the h1 with.

Comment: Can I use any element? I can't find one that works.

Comment: Well generally logos should be in h1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from your CSS. After delete the h1 tag, change your CSS from

```
 /*  HEADER */
 header h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
 header h1 a { display: block; background: url(images/logo.png); background-size:302px 21px; width: 302px; height: 21px; text-indent: -9999px; }
 header h1 + p { margin: 0; display: none; }
```

to:

```
 /*  HEADER */
 header .logo { font-size: 1.5em; }
 header .logo a { display: block; background: url(images/logo.png); background-size:302px 21px; width: 302px; height: 21px; text-indent: -9999px; }
 header .logo + p { margin: 0; display: none; }
```

Hope these help